# Installing python module rtree with a user scheme: location of DLL

Tags: python, dll, setup.py

I am installing the python module `rtree` on a cluster for which I do not have root access.

I have installed the required library `libspatialindex` into `~/var/lib` prior to the installation of the actual python package, but when I run `pip install --user rtree` I get the error:

```
OSError: libspatialindex_c.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to add `~/var/lib` to the path on my .bashrc file, but this did not help. The error is triggered by the line

```
rt = ctypes.CDLL(lib_name)
```

that is the command which should load the DLL.

Is there any way of specifying this path so that the installation script can see it?

**Edit**

I just found the solution to this: it is not `PATH`, but `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which contains information about the location of DLLs.

Adding the line

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to my `.bashrc` did the trick.

Comment: You should add this as an "answer", which can then be accepted. Wont get any points for answering your own question, but means the question is makred as answered :)